# Insert script into HTML string

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Im running on a node server and returning the HTML for a given URL

```
server.get('*', async (request, response) => {
  const url = request.protocol + '://' + request.get('host') + request.originalUrl;

  const { html } = await renderPage(url, {
    manifest,
    preload: true,
    request,
    response
  });

  //TODO: Insert script into html string in head

  response.end(html);
});
```

However, what I would like is that I could manipulate the HTML before response.end(), eg inserting a script into the head section of the HTML string... Any ideas on how to do this?

I was thinking at first I somehow could use html.replace(), but that's not the right approach I think...

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You should prepare your html first, there you can include any scripts you like. Just pass the changed values to the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing the types but if `html` is just a string, the `.replace()` method is an appropriate way to go. Depending on if you have control over the html templates which are rendered you could add a placeholder to add the script to a certain place in the html.

If you have no control I rather would just append it to the end of the body.

```
const script = `<script src="your/fancy/script.js" />`;

html.replace(/(<\s*\/\s*body)/, `${scripts}\n$1`);
```

should put the script like

```
  <div>Some content before</div>
<script src="your/fancy/script.js" />
</body>
</html>
```